# I can't connect my Amazon S3 account

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a project hosted in Amazon EC2 Ireland (Ubuntu).

I develope with CodeIgniter, and I want to use S3 to storage files.

I've used three or four specific libraries for use S3 with CodeIgniter, and none have worked. I tried official AWS SDK for PHP, and the compatibility test is OK, but the sample doesn't work. I think that the problem is access to S3.

I create in S3 Management three buckets, two in Ireland and one in US standard, and I can access files by browser, S3 Organizer (S3Fox) and Cyberduck. But I don't access with my project.

Anyone can help me?

Sorry for my bad English...

Controller amazona.php:

```
   <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Amazona extends CI_Controller {

    var $bucket = 'cubito';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('S3');
    }

    function index()
    {
/*      $data['files'] = $this->s3->getBucket('cubito'); */
        $data['texto'] = "prueba";
        $this->load->view('amazona', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

view amazona.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://cubito.s3.amazonaws.com/imagen.jpg">imagen</a>
        <img src="http://cubito.s3.amazonaws.com/imagen.jpg" />
        <p><?php echo($texto); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo($this->s3->listBuckets()); ?></p>

    </body>

</html>
```

I added a bucket policy, but still doesn't work:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1351373775750",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1351373767997",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cubito",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cubito/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I write correctly, or run the sample code of Amazon AWS SDK for PHP, no error messages. If I change anything, error message. It's like all code is alright, but the library doesn't connect with S3.

Comment: Right.  But **what** is the error message?  Provide as many details/specifics in your question (not in comments) as possible.

Comment: I'm noob, I guess. I develop in Coda, and I don't find error messages. The site load correctly before the php code. The site is: http://ec2-54-247-142-29.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/index.php/amazona . If you view the code, you advertise that the code interrupts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!!

I change the var $endpoint in the s3 library.
The original:

```
public static $endpoint = 's3.amazonaws.com';
```

The change:

```
public static $endpoint = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
```

With my first accesskey and secretkey it run!!!

Thank you everyone and sorry for my bad English.

¡¡¡Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your s3 bucket policy is not correct to list buckets.
What is your bucket policy, can you share it?

```
You Need to include the bucket itself as a resource.
"Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"]
```

**Edit:**

try this: (this is a policy for giving an IAM user to access S3)

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1351373767997",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cubito",
        "arn:aws:s3:::cubito/*"
      ]
    },
  {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
     }    
  ]
}
```

try this: (this is a policy for s3 bucket)

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1351375661442",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1351375657362",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "\"AWS\": \"*\""
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you talk about permissions, in Everyone 'Lists' is granted.

Comment: I add a bucket policy:{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1351373775750",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1351373767997",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
   },
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::cubito",
    "arn:aws:s3:::cubito/*"
   ]
  }
 ]
}

Comment: if you still have problem chech my edited answer, I added allow ListAllMyBuckets to your policy.

Comment: Amazon tell me -> Policy could not be parsed as a valid JSON string. I don't know what is the problem. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: I edited json you provided on your last comment and when I tried now, your json itself has that problem so I rewrite it now. check again my answer.

Comment: Amazon tell me this time -> Statement is missing required element - Statement "Stmt1351373767997" is missing "Principal" element. Sorry...

Comment: Ok because you are adding policy on s3 bucket itself, the format I gave you was IAM user policy. comman usage is creating a IAM user ang giving related permissions to it. I will check documantation to see what format s3 policy takes

Comment: try second policy on my answer but can't not be sure because can't test it.

Comment: why don't you create an IAM user and give permissions to that user and use that users credentials in your code. listing all buckets is a user permission.

Comment: I created a new IAM user and granted all permissions. I used the users credentials, and nothing...

Comment: did you attach the first policy on my answer to that new user?

Comment: I did it, and nothing. I'm desperate.